# IE 11 CSS Not Being Applied

Tags: css, orchardcms, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a site that is close to going live and one of the issues I am running into is the CSS on IE 11.  The CSS looks as it should on Chrome, FF, IE 8-10, however when running on IE 11 it appears as if some of the styles are not applied.  I do not have a public link or I would share that.  I know these are style definitions that are accepted by IE 11, because I tested them on [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com)

One basic example is I have is the following ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cincodenada/pXKx9/))

```
<td class="aboutDNRHome" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"> ... rest of code

.aboutDNRHome
{
    background-color: #f9f9bc;
    /*background-color:Red;*/
    width: 295px;
    padding:5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

I have verified that the html is valid.  While using the developer tools (F12) I cannot see the class when selecting the appropriate element.  Normally I would say that I have a poor CSS selector, but in this case it is a class and there is little room for error.

I am working on an Orchard CMS version 1.7.0.0.  I know there is a newer version, but the installation is actually on the clients machine and they are the ones that control upgrades etc.

Has anyone else run into style issues with IE11?  If so, what were the steps you took to resolve them.  If you have any suggestions of what else I can try to narrow down the issue, please feel free to give those too.

Comment: The styles look fine to me. What seems missing on IE 11?

Comment: Looks the same to me too: http://i.imgur.com/zI2tqnl.png. Make sure you're not emulating an older browser in your developer tools. Check your Document Mode to ensure that it is `Edge (Default)`. Press F12 to access your tools, and `Ctrl+8` to access the Emulation panel.

Comment: A note to JabberwockyDecompiler: I added the jsfiddle, so if the fiddle looks fine in your IE11, then there's something else going on, and we'll probably need more context/code.  Fork the jsfiddle and edit it to look like your site until you see the breakage.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I have been looking for the emulation panel, I could not find it.  I was not on another version, but a very helpful thing to look at.

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler The emulation panel is found in Internet Explorer 11 by pressing 12, and then Ctrl+8: http://i.imgur.com/U907kWo.png

Comment: @JonathanSampson Ahh, that is what that does, most the time my browser goes into "Not Responding" mode when I do anything other than the dom, console, or debugger.

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler That's interesting. Would you mind sharing system specs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I GOT IT!!! I used `Fiddler2` to clear the cache.  I had been clearing the history over and over and I used to use `Ctrl-D` in the `F12` developer tools to clear the browser cache with `IE10`, but  I have not been able to find that with `IE11`.  That was the issue though, stagnant files.

Note: `Ctrl + F5` was not taking care of the cached files either, only the `Fiddler2` clear cache was what worked.

Comment: Interesting, yeah CSS caching can be nasty - you might look into cache breakers (just put a GET parameter at the end of the CSS include: `<link href="include.css?cb=$randnum">`.  The $randnum should be inserted by your scripting language, and either be a random number or a timestamp, the "cb" doesn't matter, just so the URL is different.

Comment: Oh, and since you figured out and posted an answer, you should mark your own answer as the "accepted" one.